# How to get value of this binomial coefficient expression?

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to work out an upper bound (big O) of an algorithm I thought of in graph theory field. Basically I have a graph $G=(V,E)$. And a subset of vertices $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_k\} ∈ V$ such that $deg(a_i) > 2$ and $\sum^{k}_{i=1} deg(a_i) ≤ 2|E|$. ($deg(a)$ is the degree of vertex $a$)

So then what would be the exact value for this (like write it without the binomial coefficient)?

$\prod^{k}_{i=1} {deg(a_i) \choose 2}$

This is the number of steps needed for the algorithm to run.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using $\binom{n}{2}=n(n-1)/2$ you get $\frac{1}{2^k}\prod_{i=1}^k (\deg a_i)(\deg a_i - 1)$.

If $\deg a_i>2$ for $1\le i\le k$, then the value of the expression is at least $3^k$.

Comment: Wolfram says $n choose 2$ is $1/2*n*(n-1)$ from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n+choose+2

Comment: Yes, it was a typo---sorry about that.

Comment: What is the triangle (G) symbol mean?

Comment: It is the degree of a vertex of the maximum degree in the graph, $\Delta(G):=\max_{v\in V(G)} \deg v$.

Comment: Is either of the formulas you wrote exponential running time (or worse) or is it polynomial?

Comment: Also can you explain how you got the simplified expression?

Comment: Since $\deg a_i>2$ you have $\binom{\deg a_i}{2}>3\cdot 2 / 2 = 3$, so the product is at least $3^k$, which is exponential. (I deleted the "simplified" expression as it is irrelevant to the question---sorry for confusion.)